# Some sample users don't work in skype web sdk

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am new to Skype web sdk. I am trying to use the samples provided, and especially the chat-service script.
In order to test the sdk, I use the credentials from *ucwa.skype.com*, as mentionned in here *msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/downloadrunsamples*.

There are 3 credentials there. When I use the second one (aka Fernando), I am able to use the chat-service script and to chat with my skype for business (which is an office-365 account). But when I try to do the same thing using another test account (also from ucwa), I can't manage to receive the chat invitation on my desktop app.
I am awara that the sdk does not support office-365 account but here I am connecting in the account supplied by ucwa.

I ran the sample with both account at the same time (in 2 different windows), here is the only difference between the account that actually works and the other one :

[The one that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUTkf.png)

[The other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kl39.png)

I have not change any parameter (just running the sample in local with wamp server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tokens expired and the whole process now works on the 3 accounts provided by ucwa.

I don't know if there is a way to generate new tokens before the old one expire but if there is such a way, it is probably the solution to my former problem